# i can't get access to my admin panel

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

here is my php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['admlogin']))
{
    $u = $_POST['admname'];
    $pass = $_POST['admpass'];
    $_SESSION['admin']=$u;
    $p = md5($pass);
    $q = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user='$u' AND pass='$p'";
    $cq = mysqli_query($con,$q);
    $ret = mysqli_num_rows($cq);
    if($ret == true)
    {
        header('location:backend.php');

    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Wrong Login Details, Try Again!')</script>";
    }
```

here is my sql code:

```
INSERT INTO admin (id, user, pass ) VALUES

(1, 'admin', 'admin'),

(2, 'friends', 'friends');
```

code image:

[image]

another image of sql code:

[image]

Comment: uhm you md5 your input but the pass you inserted is plain text? assuming it even gets there, you haven't given any information about what does not work, atleast debug to find out where it goes wrong before posting

Comment: have you tried echoing the query?it will let u know what parameters are being passed

Comment: just by skipping md5 , it did work. that was so unfortunate. thanx for ur kind response.

Answer (score 1):

1) Form your `insert query` it shows that `password` for `admin` is `admin`. that is not in `md5` then why you `md5` your `password` at the time of comparison.

2) Remove `md5` from `$pass` as you have not saved `md5` `password` in `database`. And add `mysqli_error()` `function` to see any `errors`

```
 if(isset($_POST['admlogin']))
    {
        $u = $_POST['admname'];
        $pass = $_POST['admpass'];
        $_SESSION['admin']=$u;
       // $p = md5($pass); remove this or save password with md5 in db
        $p = $pass;
        $q = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user='$u' AND pass='$p'";
        $cq = mysqli_query($con,$q) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $ret = mysqli_num_rows($cq);
        if($ret == true)
        {
            header('location:backend.php');

        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Wrong Login Details, Try Again!')</script>";
        }
```

Comment: thank u so much. md5 unfortunately added. right now my problem is solved.

Comment: @S.H.Kanon If it solved your problem then mark it your answer :)